# Reduce Vector/Matrix mod N

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

If I have a vector such as below and want to reduce it mod a number, how can I do this?

```
V = {{176}, {648}};
MatrixForm[V]
MatrixForm[V, Modulus -> 26]
```

Both MatrixForms above will output <176, 648>  but I would like it to output mod 26
so that I would have <20, 24>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
V = {{176}, {648}};

MatrixForm[Mod[V, 26]]
```

[image]